# Workflow Definition Language `equals` doesn't return boolean value

Tags: boolean, azure-logic-apps, workflow-definition-language

I'm working with the following Azure Logic App expression (Workflow Definition Language (WDL)):

```
equals(
    int(
        formatDateTime(
            subtractFromTime(
                utcNow(),
                7,
                'Day'
            ),
            'MM'
        )
    ),
    2
)
```

The [WDL docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#equals) say that the `equals` function should return with a `boolean` value.

[image]

**However, I'm seeing a `string` response, NOT `boolean`:**

- The action shown on top is an actual `boolean`
- Note the lower case "t" in `true`
- Whereas the action shown on the bottom is the issue

[image]

[image]

**Tried:**

- Wrapping the above function in the `bool` keyword, same `string` result(!)

**Whats going on here?**

**EDIT 1:**

- Just deleted all actions and tested again, seems to be working now
- Weird

[image]

Comment: If I've understood you correctly then you're using the expression to populate a compose action, is that right?  If so, I don't have your issue, it comes out with a boolean, not a string and that's whether I use compose or initialize variable.

Comment: Hm. And you're using Azure Logic Apps, not Power Automate, correct?

Comment: I just deleted all the actions and tested again. This time, its correct (see **EDIT 1:** above).

Comment: That is weird ... and annoying.  :-)  Good news though.

Comment: And now it's happening to me... You know, graphical languages with type safety have been developed before, I don't know why Microsoft struggles with it so much...